# Use subelements into a API call in Ansible

Tags: ansible

Im tryng to make an API call with differents URI and diferent JSON in the same task.

These are my vars:

```
api_templates:
  - name                    : 
     - 'template1'
     - 'template2'
    url                     :
      - 'http://localhost:80/template1'
      - 'http://localhost:80/template2'
    file                    :
      - '../files/template1.json'
      - '../files/template2.json'
```

And I'm using this code:

```
- name: Inserting templates
  uri:
    url: "{{ item.0.url }}"
    method: PUT
    body: "{{ lookup('file', '{{ item.1 }}') }}"
    body_format: json
  with_subelements:
     - "{{ api_templates }}"
     - file
```

But it doesn't work correctly.

I need that the first iteration of the task execute the API call, with template1, the first URL and using the first file and so on..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want your task to loop two times, with these sets of data:

- `(template1, http://localhost:80/template1, ../files/template1.json)`
- `(template2, http://localhost:80/template2, ../files/template2.json)`

You don't want *subelements*, you want to loop over three lists in parallel. That means you want `with_together` (the old way) or a `loop` with the `zip` filter (the new way), like this:

First, I would suggest restructuring your data.  Right now, `api_templates` is a list of one item (which is a dictionary). We can simplify things by removing that extra level of hierarchy:

```
api_templates:
  name                    : 
   - 'template1'
   - 'template2'
  url                     :
    - 'http://localhost:80/template1'
    - 'http://localhost:80/template2'
  file                    :
    - '../files/template1.json'
    - '../files/template2.json'
```

Then we can loop over your three lists (`name`, `url`, and `file`) like this:

```
- debug:
    msg: "name: {{ item.0 }}, url: {{ item.1 }}, file: {{ item.2 }}"
  loop: "{{ api_templates.name|zip(api_templates.url, api_templates.file) | list }}"
```

Or using your task as an example:

```
- name: Inserting templates
  uri:
    url: "{{ item.1 }}"
    method: PUT
    body: "{{ lookup('file', '{{ item.2 }}') }}"
    body_format: json
  loop: "{{ api_templates.name|zip(api_templates.url, api_templates.file) | list }}"
```

Since you seem to be ignoring the `name` list, you could remove one term from that `loop` expression:

```
loop: "{{ api_templates.url | zip(api_templates.file) | list }}"
```

If `api_templates` is **really** a list, like this:

```
api_templates:
  - name                    : 
     - 'template1'
     - 'template2'
    url                     :
      - 'http://localhost:80/template1'
      - 'http://localhost:80/template2'
    file                    :
      - '../files/template1.json'
      - '../files/template2.json'
  - name                    : 
     - 'template3'
     - 'template4'
    url                     :
      - 'http://localhost:80/template3'
      - 'http://localhost:80/template4'
    file                    :
      - '../files/template3.json'
      - '../files/template4.json'
```

...then things are a little bit more complicated, because you would need a
nested loop to do what you want.  Ansible doesn't directly support nested
loops, but you can do fake it via the `include` mechanism. For example, move
the "inserting templates" task into a file called `process_template.yml`, that
looks something like:

```
- name: Inserting templates
  uri:
    url: "{{ item.0 }}"
    method: PUT
    body: "{{ lookup('file', '{{ item.1 }}') }}"
    body_format: json
  loop: "{{ template.url | zip(template.file) | list }}"
```

And then in your `playbook.yml`, call it like this:

```
- include_tasks: process_template.yml
  loop: "{{ api_templates }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: template
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I got this error: "Unexpected failure in finding the lookup named ... in the available lookup plugins" Is "loop" not deprecated? Im using 2.7 ansible version..

Comment: `with_*` is deprecated, `loop` is the preferred syntax in 2.7 and later. This was all tested with 2.7.10. What was the complete error message? You replaced the key information with `...`.

Comment: You can see a complete successful run of this playbook at https://asciinema.org/a/6BKu21joxgkQttsvzK3qG4I9r (with your `uri` tasks wrapped in a `debug` task).

Comment: @larsks: Correct wording is important here. with_* is **not deprecated** and loop is **recommended**. See [Migrating from with_X to loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/porting_guides/porting_guide_2.5.html#migrating-from-with-x-to-loop). "Recommended [means](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) "there
   may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a
   particular item, but the full implications must be understood and
   carefully weighed before choosing a different course". There are cases where with_* is a simpler solution.

Comment: I...don't think the practical implications of that are substantially different than what I said, but thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Practical implication of [Deprecated functionality](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/6.9_technical_notes/chap-red_hat_enterprise_linux-6.9_technical_notes-deprecated_functionality) is "Deprecated functionality will likely not be supported in future major releases of this product and is not recommended for new deployments". Do you suggest with_* "will likely not be supported in future ..."?. This would be substantially different from what the documentation says.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to loop *include_tasks*. The play below

```
- include_tasks: uri-put.yml
  loop: "{{ api_templates }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: uri
```

with the included file

```
> cat uri-put.yml
- debug: msg="{{ item.0 }} {{ item.1 }} {{ item.2 }}"
  with_together:
    - "{{ uri.name }}"
    - "{{ uri.url }}"
    - "{{ uri.file }}"
```

gives (cat msg):

```
"msg": "template1 http://localhost:80/template1 ../files/template1.json"
"msg": "template2 http://localhost:80/template2 ../files/template2.json"
```

Comment: It's not only remarkably similar. In fact, it's the same compared to what I posted. A good example why with_* should not be deprecated.